# Postgres: How do I format an int timestamp as readable date string?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a column that contains unix timestamps - an int representing the number of seconds since the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). They look like this: `1347085827`. How do I format this as a human-readable date string in my SELECT query?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Postgresql has a handy built-in function for this: `to_timestamp()`. Just wrap that function around the column you want:

```
Select a, b, to_timestamp(date_int) FROM t_tablename
```

Comment: Then use `to_char` if you want to output a specific date/time/timestamp format.

Comment: @CraigRinger yep, then read an article "how to convert timestamp to date").

The answer is nearly not correct. it should be `to_timestamp(date_int)::date` to get 
`2022-05-26` from `1653592838` or `TO_CHAR(to_timestamp(date_int), 'dd-mm-yyyy')` for `26-05-2022`