# POSTGRESQL: Error: date format not recognized

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have a table "user_order" with columns "user_id", "code" (character varying) and created_date_key (integer). I am trying to write a query which displays all records for code 26 and date greater that '12-5-2013 23:59:59'.

```
Select *
from user_order
where code like 26 ::text
and to_date(created_date_key ::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD') > to_date ('12-5-2013 23:59:59' ::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

ERROR: date format not recognized.

Comment: Why are you storing a timestamp as an `integer`? `to_date()` converts a string (`varchar`, `text`) to a date. You cannot pass it an integer. Think about it: how could an integer even when casted to a string possibly have the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`

Comment: Assuming your integer is a Unix timestamp or similar (seconds since epoch), you should find what you need here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747317/postgres-compare-timestamp-with-long-unix-timestamp and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328817/postgres-how-do-i-format-an-int-timestamp-as-readable-date-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
  from user_order
 where code like 26 ::text
   and to_date(created_date_key ::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD') > '12-5-2013 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Please give some explanation about your answer rather than just the SQL.

Comment: `to_date(created_date_key ::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` is not going to work and is exactly what Rohit already tried.

Comment: Convert the integer date to date (1st to string and then to date) as you cannot convert a number directly to date and then check if the date converted is greater than '12-5-2013 23:59:59'

Answer (score 1):

created_date_key should be timestamp and not integer.

Comment: I can't change the table structure. That's the way it was build. Just help me with the select statement.

Comment: Try to remove the dashes then: Instead of YYYY-MM-DD use that format: YYYYMMDD

Answer (score 0):

String values need to be included within single quotes. You do not need to specify text to convert the data type. to_timestamp function is used to convert the text data to timestamp value. The following query would select the required data:

```
Select *
from user_order
where code = '26'
and created_date_key > to_timestamp ('12-5-2013 23:59:59', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

**References**:

1. [SELECT on PostgreSQL Manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html).  There are a lot of examples on this page.
2. [Data Type Formatting Functions on PostgreSQL Manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: created_date_key is a integer. You are trying to compare integer with timestamp.